# Geoserver Image Pyramid with JPEG Compression

Tags: gis, gdal, geoserver

I have an Image Pyramid (created using gdal_retile) that I want to import into Geoserver (2.8.2, using the Image Pyramid plugin) and publish as WMS.

I have been able to do this successfully using GeoTIFF images, however as we are storing many terabytes of imagery, we would like to use JPEG compressed TIFF.

If I run gdal_retile using the compression argument, e.g:

> @python %OSGEO4W_ROOT%\bin\gdal_retile.py -v -r bilinear -levels
>   %LEVELS% -tileIndex TileIndex.shp -ps %PIXELS% %PIXELS% -co
>   "TILED=YES" **-co "COMPRESS=JPEG"** -targetDir %INPUT%\PROCESSED\
>   --optfile %INPUT%\tilelist.txt

Then Geoserver errors when trying to publish the layer but doesn't seem to provide a complete error log (I've pasted what it supplied below).

**There's some supporting info below - hopefully this is enough - thanks in advance!**

I have also tried this on version 2.7.6, with the same results.

My folder structure after creating the Image Pyramid data store is as follows (NOTE: listed output/1 only as an example, all Level folders have the same structure):

../output

- Level Folders (0,1,2,3,4,5)
- output.prj
- output.properties

../output/1

- Contains images (JPEG Compressed TIFF)
- Tile Index (1.shp,1.shx,1.prj,1.dbf)
- Properties File (1.properties)
- Fix File (1.fix) - not sure what this is.

I have run gdal_info on one of the outputted TIF files:

```
Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: C:\geoserver\data\pyramids\constantia_comp\PROCESSED\output\1\constantia2
ransparent_mosaic_group1_4_3.tif
Size is 2048, 1757
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS 84 / UTM zone 34S",
    GEOGCS["WGS 84",
        DATUM["WGS_1984",
            SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],
        UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]],
    PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",0],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",21],
    PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",500000],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",10000000],
    UNIT["metre",1,
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","9001"]],
    AXIS["Easting",EAST],
    AXIS["Northing",NORTH],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","32734"]]
Origin = (262297.873039999980000,6229349.579940000500000)
Pixel Size = (0.224620000000000,-0.224620000000000)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=JPEG
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  262297.873, 6229349.580) ( 18d25'29.43"E, 34d 2'58.65"S)
Lower Left  (  262297.873, 6228954.923) ( 18d25'29.04"E, 34d 3'11.45"S)
Upper Right (  262757.895, 6229349.580) ( 18d25'47.35"E, 34d 2'59.02"S)
Lower Right (  262757.895, 6228954.923) ( 18d25'46.96"E, 34d 3'11.83"S)
Center      (  262527.884, 6229152.251) ( 18d25'38.19"E, 34d 3' 5.24"S)
Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 2 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 3 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue
  Mask Flags: PER_DATASET ALPHA
Band 4 Block=256x256 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Alpha
```

Error Log:

```
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Error occurred while building the resources for the configuration page 
at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage.buildLayerInfo(NewLayerPage.java:356) 
at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage$8.onClick(NewLayerPage.java:281) 
at org.geoserver.web.wicket.SimpleAjaxLink$1.onClick(SimpleAjaxLink.java:46) 
at org.apache.wicket.ajax.markup.html.AjaxLink$1.onEvent(AjaxLink.java:68) 
at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AjaxEventBehavior.respond(AjaxEventBehavior.java:177) 
at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:300) 
at org.apache.wicket.request.target.component.listener.BehaviorRequestTarget.processEvents(BehaviorRequestTarget.java:119) 
at org.apache.wicket.request.AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.processEvents(AbstractRequestCycleProcessor.java:92) 
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.processEventsAndRespond(RequestCycle.java:1250) 
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.step(RequestCycle.java:1329) 
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.steps(RequestCycle.java:1436) 
at org.apache.wicket.RequestCycle.request(RequestCycle.java:545) 
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doGet(WicketFilter.java:484) 
at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketServlet.doGet(WicketServlet.java:138) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ServletWrappingController.handleRequestInternal(ServletWrappingController.java:159) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController.handleRequest(AbstractController.java:153) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.handle(SimpleControllerHandlerAdapter.java:48) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:923) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:852) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:882) 
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:778) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707) 
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1093) 
at org.geoserver.filters.ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.doFilter(ThreadLocalsCleanupFilter.java:28) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084) 
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:75) 
at org.geoserver.wms.animate.AnimatorFilter.doFilter(AnimatorFilter.java:71) 
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter$Chain.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:71) 
at org.geoserver.filters.SpringDelegatingFilter.doFilter(SpringDelegatingFilter.java:46) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084) 
at org.geoserver.platform.AdvancedDispatchFilter.doFilter(AdvancedDispatchFilter.java:50) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084) 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:311) 
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69) 
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:116) 
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:83) 
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73) 
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92) 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) 
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69) 
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) 
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73) 
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92) 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) 
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:54) 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) 
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69) 
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:182) 
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73) 
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92) 
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GeoServerUserNamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:116) 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) 
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69) 
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:146) 
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73) 
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92) 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) 
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:69) 
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) 
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter$1.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:53) 
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter$NestedFilterChain.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:73) 
at org.geoserver.security.filter.GeoServerCompositeFilter.doFilter(GeoServerCompositeFilter.java:92) 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:323) 
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:173) 
at org.geoserver.security.GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.doFilter(GeoServerSecurityFilterChainProxy.java:135) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) 
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084) 
at org.geoserver.filters.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:83) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084) 
at org.geoserver.filters.GZIPFilter.doFilter(GZIPFilter.java:42) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084) 
at org.geoserver.filters.SessionDebugFilter.doFilter(SessionDebugFilter.java:48) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084) 
at org.geoserver.filters.FlushSafeFilter.doFilter(FlushSafeFilter.java:44) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084) 
at org.vfny.geoserver.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(SetCharacterEncodingFilter.java:109) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1084) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:360) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:181) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:726) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:405) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:206) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:324) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:505) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:828) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:514) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:211) 
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:380) 
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:395) 
at org.mortbay.thread.BoundedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(BoundedThreadPool.java:450) Caused by: org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: Unable to load properties from:C:\geoserver\data\pyramids\constantia_comp\PROCESSED\test\0\datastore.properties 
at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicReader.<init>(ImageMosaicReader.java:470) 
at org.geotools.gce.imagepyramid.ImagePyramidReader.getImageMosaicReaderForLevel(ImagePyramidReader.java:655) 
at org.geotools.gce.imagepyramid.ImagePyramidReader.loadRequestedTiles(ImagePyramidReader.java:484) 
at org.geotools.gce.imagepyramid.ImagePyramidReader.loadTiles(ImagePyramidReader.java:431) 
at org.geotools.gce.imagepyramid.ImagePyramidReader.read(ImagePyramidReader.java:372) 
at org.geotools.coverage.grid.io.AbstractGridCoverage2DReader.read(AbstractGridCoverage2DReader.java:249) 
at org.geoserver.catalog.CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.read(CoverageDimensionCustomizerReader.java:227) 
at org.geoserver.catalog.SingleGridCoverage2DReader.read(SingleGridCoverage2DReader.java:141) 
at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverage(CatalogBuilder.java:974) 
at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverage(CatalogBuilder.java:855) 
at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPage.buildLayerInfo(NewLayerPage.java:346) ... 97 more Caused by: org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: Unable to load properties from:C:\geoserver\data\pyramids\constantia_comp\PROCESSED\test\0\datastore.properties 
at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicReader.initReaderFromURL(ImageMosaicReader.java:643) 
at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicReader.<init>(ImageMosaicReader.java:468) ... 107 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to load properties from:C:\geoserver\data\pyramids\constantia_comp\PROCESSED\test\0\datastore.properties 
at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.CatalogManager.createGranuleCatalogProperties(CatalogManager.java:180) 
at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.ImageMosaicReader.initReaderFromURL(ImageMosaicReader.java:576) ... 108 more
```

Comment: does C:\geoserver\data\pyramids\constantia_comp\PROCESSED\test\0\datastore.properties exist?

Comment: Thanks for your reply:

The properties file exists, but was named by the folder (e.g 0.properties). If I rename the file in /test/0 to 'datastore.properties', I get another error: http://pastebin.com/c1qCLxta

I wonder if I am doing something in the wrong order, I was under the impression I should let geoserver create the properties file for me, but perhaps this isn't the case?

Comment: does tomcat (or whoever is running geoserver) have write permission to those directories?

Comment: It's running as a windows service - I've set up a new user with full control over the directory and restarted but still no luck. The only info I can find regarding the error message "This plugin accepts File, URL or String. The string may describe a File or an URL" seems to relate to file permissions so I am a bit stumped. I'd be interested to know if you have any other thoughts but otherwise I'll go back to using mapserver for now!
Thank you for your help.